# Is it possible to prove that $1+1=2$ as an implication of the axioms of the field of rational numbers and not using Peano's axioms?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the Rudin's Principles it is proved that the field axioms imply $0x=0$ indeed $0x+0x=(0+0)x=0x$ hence $0x=0$. I was wondering if it is possible to prove $1+1=2$ in a similar way (for example that a different result would imply the violation of the axioms of the field of rational numbers). I'm a engineering student and I know only basic math (linear algebra and calculus). Thank you.

Comment: You can't prove it but take as a definition of $2$. However, $2\ne 0$ can't be proved.

Comment: What is the definition of 2?

Comment: @Bercy indeed in the field with two elements you have $2=0$